# jquery ui tabs sub navigation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm still new to web design, and have dove into jquery ui. I'm attempting to use the tabs function as navigation for a page I'm designing. Anyone have any idea as to how I can make the sub navigation li's behave as the tab li's? And also when a sub nav li is clicked, to make the parent tab li highlighted, but the content panel display the sub menu selection. Anyone have a clue where I control what is displayed in the selected tab?

I've attempted to use the little jquery skills I have. I wrote a click function that made the about tab the active tab, but it displays the content from the about tab, when I would like it to display the info from the sub nav selection. I've also attempted to just add the active class to the about menu, and it creates a hideous output on the page.

Here is my html

```
<div id="tabs" style="width: 1000px; margin: 4px auto; padding: 0px;">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li id="aboutLink"><a href="#about">About</a>
                <ul id="subNav" style="color: #220c00;">
                    <li><a href="#about">About Iota</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chapterHistory">Chapter History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chapterOfficers">Chapter Officers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#communityPartners">Community Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chapterEvents">Chapter Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#interestedInIota">Interested in Iota</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.iotaphitheta.org">National Site</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brothers Only</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And this is my jquery

```
main = function () {
$('#subNav').addClass('subNav');
$('#aboutLink').hover(function () {
    $('#subNav').removeClass('subNav');}, 
    function () { $('#subNav').addClass('subNav');
    });
$('#subNav').children().click( function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({active: 1});
    $('#subNav').removeClass('subNav');
    });
    };
$(document).ready(main);
```

Fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/leggosteveo/d3byhbd9/2/

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle so we can see it https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have created a fiddle @JoshStevens

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/leggosteveo/d3byhbd9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are tons of jQuery menus already created that should do what you need. Here's one that lets you customize what you need right on their website including the menu options and looks.  It also displays the HTML and javascript its using so if nothing else you could use it as a model.

http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-jay-dropdown-menu#

When using an existing product you'll save time and most of the time you can trust its been much more thoroughly tested.

Comment: great point about not re-inventing the wheel. I just really want to understand javascript and be able to truly solve problems. But in future instances I will certainly remember your advice to search for proven methods.

Answer (score 0):

So I read your comment, that you really want to understand `javascript`, thing is Simple menus using `CSS3` and `HTML5` are becoming quite popular because you don’t need `JQuery` or `JavaScript` to add animations

Just changed the styles as i didn't use jquery ui

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/997skw7b/)

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul class="parent-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Iota</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter History</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter Officers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>  
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">National Site</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Brothers Only</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
p, ul, li, div, nav {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#menu {
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.parent-menu {
    background-color: #0c8fff;
    min-width:200px;
    float:left;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu ul li a {
    padding:10px 15px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#007ee9;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#2e2e2e;
}
```

To change the speed of the animation set the numeric value in this code as you like

```
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 transition: left 200ms ease-in;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that's great info as well, as I am also wanting to learn best/latest practices in designing sites, and your fiddle works perfectly for what I am trying to accomplish.